# Vs 2005 device connection

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, visual-studio-2005

I 'm developing a windows device.

I'm using vs 2005 and when I want to connect the device I get these errors:

Can't connect to Rpc server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwWTn.png)

and

Connection failed the bootstrap could not be loaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUo8j.png)

Please can you help me with this...

Comment: A lot has changed since 2005.  Most server want a secure connection which is not possible in VS 2005 with current encryption algorithms.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to deploy an app to a PocketPC 2003 device. As already mentioned, VS2005 and PocketPC 2003 are very outdated.

Possibly you are trying the wrong. What is the read device model you are trying to connect to? What is the OS you are running on the VS2005 PC and on the device? I.e. Windows 10/11 have totally changed and do not allow ActiveSync connections from scratch.

Here are some general hints abou Device connections (ActiveSync, Windows Mobile Device Center):
http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/09/05/windows-mobile-device-center-wmdc-or-activesync-troubleshooting/

Please prvide as much details as you can, if you need further assistance.

Comment: Hello, ActiveSync is not supported on Windows 10. I use windows mobile device center to connect the device to the computer. The problem is not connecting the device to the computer, but the problem is that the device is not connected with the project in vs-2005.

Comment: If device is connected, you can use Remote Tools like File Explorer etc? When you deploy a project to the device, a remote agent is started via active sync (or WMDC, same tool with different name), the agent is then used to receive and start the application. Some details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms228708(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. I am still missing some more details.